# GS Auto Advance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm new to coding and just started working with GoogleSheets Scripts for work. We are going to be displaying a live GS on a large TV for people to review their upcoming work. The problem I have is that there are too many rows to display on a single screen so we need to set it up to advance down automatically over a period of time.

```
function sheetProgress(){
    onOpen();
    continueTime();
}

function onOpen(e) {
    Utilities.sleep(5000)
    var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = file.getActiveSheet();
    var row = 65;
    file.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(row,1));
}

function continueTime() {
    Utilities.sleep(5000)
    var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = file.getActiveSheet();
    var row = 130;
    file.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(row,1));
}
```

If I run the 2 functions independently they work fine. But I'm not sure how to have them run in sequence to have the sheet advance down several rows at a time over so many seconds.

Comment: Why run them independently, you could just have one `onOpen` that scrolls  from row 1 to row 65 to row 130? Unless of course, at some point you scroll back to the top and repeat; though you could do all that in time-driven trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side scripts or bookmarklets. In chrome, after entering the url like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]/edit#gid=[SHEET_ID]&range=A2
```

The above url selects A2. Then in address bar, type

```
javascript:setInterval(()=>location.replace(String(location).replace(/\d+$/,d=>d=Number(d)+50)),2000);void(0);
```

This will change `A2` to `A52`,`A102` and so on every 2 seconds.